# Why does adding a . in %s prevent the number from getting printed?

Tags: bash

I am trying to learn commands in Bash and came across these examples. Why does adding a `'.'` prevent the sequence number from getting printed?

This is the behaviour I want, but I couldn't find anything on [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf).

```
printf "%.sI" $(seq 10)
```

> `IIIIIIIIII`

```
printf "%sI" $(seq 10)
```

> `1I2I3I4I5I6I7I8I9I10I`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`printf` allows you to specify a precision which is applicable even for strings:

Relevant statements from the [printf(3) manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.') followed by an optional decimal digit string.
>
> If the precision is given as just '.', or the precision is negative, the precision is taken to be zero.
>
> This gives ... the maximum number of characters to be printed from a string for `s` and `S` conversions.

So `printf '%.s'` is equivalent to `printf '%.0s'`, which suppresses the output from the subsequent string parameter.